# Printing in Sap Fiori

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I was wondering if the printing option is available in a sap fiori applications or not ? If so, is it on the desktop only or mobile also ? If you could please publish a code sample i would be grateful.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create print in SAPUI5 applications by constructing HTML using javascript. It will be in both desktop and mobile.

```
    var temp = this.getView().getModel();
        console.log(temp);
        var nameofWork =
            "A variable object is an abstract concept." + 
            "In different context types, physically, it’s presented" +
            " using different object. For example, in the global context" + 
            " the variable object is the global object itself (that’s why we have an ability to refer global variables via property names of the global object).";
        var mainView = "<html><body><div><h2>Name of work:</h2><div><p>" + nameofWork + "</p></div></div>";

        mainView += "</body></html>";
        var ctrlString = "width=600px,height=600px";
        sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
        var wind = window.open("", "PrintWindow", ctrlString);
        wind.document.write(mainView);
        wind.print();
        wind.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
concerning the open method, the second parameter "PrintWindow" is a dialog i have to create ?

Comment: No need it will automatically create  only you need to construct html page based on your requirement.